# VS-Code doesn't plot gpd.GeoSeries().plot()

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, geopandas

Hi I am trying to plot Geo-Data using VS-Code with geopandas

My code looks as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geopandas.geoseries
from shapely.geometry import Point
import random
import matplotlib as plt

#offset a point randomly
def point_offset(point):
    x_alt = point.x
    y_alt = point.y
    x_neu = x_alt + random.randrange(-100,100,1)
    y_neu = y_alt + random.randrange(-100,100,1)
    punkt_neu = Point(x_neu,y_neu)
    return punkt_neu

#define point and calculate new point
sternwarte = Point(2600000,1200000)
sternwarte_neu = point_offset(sternwarte)
print(sternwarte_neu)

#why do these two lines don't work??
ax = gpd.GeoSeries([point_offset(sternwarte) for x in range(1,1000)]).plot()
gpd.GeoSeries(sternwarte).plot(ax = ax, color = "red")
```

The outpot looks like this:

```
PS C:\Users\giebe\projects\GIS\Coding_2> cd 'c:\Users\giebe\projects\GIS\Coding_2'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\giebe\Anaconda\envs\buerktim\python.exe' 'c:\Users\giebe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.44104\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '54586' 'c:\Users\giebe\projects\GIS\Coding_2\Monte_Carlo.py'
POINT (2600075 1200034)
PS C:\Users\giebe\projects\GIS\Coding_2>
```

It seems like the program is running correctly, but the last two lines don't get exececuted (the plot doesn't show up)

In the following link it is said I can just use the .plot() Funktion to plot geodata:
http://geopandas.org/mapping.html

I copied the code from a course in uni, but they are using the Spyder IDE. I really like VS-Code because of its Autocomplete function and Intelisense.

What important part am I missing?

UPDATE: When I try to run the following code suggested by martinfleis in the comments:

```
world = gpd.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
```

i get the following error:

```
"The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas."
ImportError: The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas.
```

When i use the, by the error message suggested import:

```
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
```

It doesn^t seem to find the descartes package:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'descartes'
  File "C:\Users\giebe\projects\GIS\Coding_2\Monte_Carlo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
```

So i installed descartes in the Terminal using

```
conda install descartes matplotlib
```

It shows up with the pip freeze command so descartes is installed.
But the error still persists.(No module named descartes)

Comment: Your code looks okay. Can you try `world = gpd.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))` and then `world.plot()` what would happen?

Comment: `ImportError: The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas      from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch`

Comment: @martinfleis: Thanks a lot I updated my comment with more detail :D

Comment: `conda install descartes matplotlib` should install optional dependencies needed for plotting.

Comment: If it still says 'No module named descartes', then you probably installed Descartes in the different environment or not installed. You can also try `pip install descartes` if conda is not cooperating.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did now install the package i did before in the terminal within vs code and the pip install but had to open the anaconda prompt through the anaconda navigator...  The package is now installed and the code seems to run but now plot window is popping up or anything being executed it seems.   Thank you a lot you've been a great help